# How to map the current directory in the volume of kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to map the current directory to a volume of Kubernetes on windows.

I can do this using hostPath, but I can not get the current directory in my deployment.

Usually we use ./ to pass the current directory but kubernetes does not recognize it.

How can I use the corresponding ./ in windows kubernetes?

Here's the way I'm trying to do:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: testeleitor
labels:
    app: leitoreventos
spec:
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: leitoreventos
    tier: backend
replicas: 1
template:
    metadata:
    labels: 
        app: leitoreventos
        tier: backend
    spec:
    restartPolicy: Always
    containers:
    - image: leitordeeventos:v1.6.1
        name: leitor
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5555 
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/binarios/test/
          name: test-volume
    volumes:
    - name: test-volume
      hostPath:
        path: ./test/
        type: Directory
```

Comment: By current you mean the directory from which you run kubectl?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the current directory of a Deployment"; by the time the Pod starts, you are already in the container

Comment: @Max Lobur, Yes, the directory from where I will run the kubectl command.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I would like to map the current directory so I do not have to pass the absolute path to the volume.
Or is it mandatory to pass the absolute path in all mappings of kubernetes volumes?

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible. You can only map k8s host dir into a pod, but usually, you don't know which host it will start on. So I suggest to put the data you need to S3 or somewhere, and download it inside the container.

Comment: @GladsonBruno it's always mandatory to specify the absolute path in all mappings; there is no such thing as a relative path volume mapping, just as Max said